# With FParsec how would I parse: line ending in newline <|> a line ending with eof

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm parsing a file and want to throw away certain lines of the file I'm not interested in.  I've been able to get this to work for all cases except for when the last line is a throwaway and does not end in newline.

I've tried constructing an `endOfInput` rule and joining it with a `skipLine` rule via `<|>`.  This is all wrapped in a `many`.  Tweaking everything I seem to either get a 'many succeeds without consuming input...' error or a fail on the `skipLine` rule when I don't try some kind of back track.

```
let skipLine = many (noneOf "\n") .>> newline |>> fun x -> [string x]

let endOfInput = many (noneOf "\n") .>> eof |>> fun x -> [string x]

test (many (skipLine <|> endOfInput)) "And here is the next.\nThen the last."
```

** this errors out on the skipLine parser at the last line

I've tried

```
let skipLine = many (noneOf "\n") .>>? newline |>> fun x -> [string x]
```

... and ...

```
let skipLine = many (noneOf "\n") .>> newline |>> fun x -> [string x]

test (many (attempt skipLine <|> endOfInput)) "And here is the next.\nThen the last."
```

** these produce the many error

Note: the output functions are just place holders to get these to work with my other rules.  I haven't gotten into figuring out how to format the output.
This is my first time using FParsec and I'm new to F#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FParsec actually has a built-in parser that does exactly what you're looking for: [`skipRestOfLine`](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.skipRestOfLine). It terminates on either newlines or eof, just like what you're looking for.

If you want to try to implement it yourself as a learning exercise, let me know and I'll try to help you figure out the problem. But if you just want a parser that skips characters until the end of the line, the built-in `skipRestOfLine` is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had used skipRestOfLine previously and ended up running into the 'many' errors, but after your suggestion I decided to try again.  This time combining the 2 rules into one: let skipLine = (skipRestOfLine false) .>>? newline |>> fun x-> [string x]   And that did the trick!  Thanks! I'd been chewing on this one for a couple of days.

Comment: ...for others who might see this.  I tried just straight (skipRestOfLine true) as well but that got me back to the 'many succeeds without consuming input...' error.

Comment: Just `let skipLine = (skipRestOfLine true)` *should* have been all you needed. If you were running into the "many succeeds without consuming input" error, then that's probably because you were doing `many (attempt skipLine)` instead of just `many skipLine`, though it's hard to be sure without seeing all of your code. It seems like you haven't quite understood https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#parsing-alternatives yet — you might benefit from going back and rereading that part of the FParsec tutorial, aiming for better understanding of how FParsec's backtracking works in detail.

Comment: **test (many (skipRestOfLine true)) "And here is the next.\nThen the last."**  where the test function is the same used in the tutorial.  It produces the many error.  I think there was a warning in the tutorial or docs that it would.  But you're right I haven't yet gotten the hang some of the concepts - when some of the parsers actually 'consume' input and when/how parser state changes is a big one.  I just need to spend more time with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach of parsing such a files with using an Option type,
it'll help you to parse files with newlines in the end or skip blank lines in the middle. I've got the solution from that post - [fparsec key-value parser fails to parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623599/fparsec-key-value-parser-fails-to-parse) . Parsing of a text file with integer values in one column:

```
module OptionIntParser =
 open FParsec
 open System
 open System.IO
  
 let pCell: Parser<int, unit> = pint32 |>> fun x -> x
 let pSome =   pCell |>> Some
 let pNone =  (restOfLine false) >>% None
 let pLine = (attempt pSome) <|> pNone
 let pAllover = sepBy pLine newline  |>> List.choose id

 let readFile filePath =
    let rr = File.OpenRead(filePath)    
    use reader = new IO.StreamReader(rr)    
    reader.ReadToEnd()

 let testStr = readFile("./test1.txt")

 let runAll s  =
  let res = run pAllover s in
    match res with
     | Success (rows, _, _) ->  rows 
     | Failure (s, _, _) -> []

 let myTest =
   let res = runAll testStr
   res |> List.iter (fun (x) -> Console.WriteLine(x.ToString() ))
```